# textbox not showing decimal places\

Tags: vb.net, decimal

[image: Form1 layout]

From the userform
numberupdown 1 is F,
numberupdown 2 is L,
numberupdown 3 is W,
Text box is CF,
Calculate is button1.

The formula for the calculation is

> F-(F*(L^2)/(W^2)

Basically this takes the flow of an irrigation Pivot, and punched out the flow that the cornering are requires to operate.

The input figures are metric the result is imperial US GPM.

I've translated that to:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click
    Dim AA, BB, CC, DD As Integer    'sets up the variables
    AA = F.Value * 15.8503    'takes the value in f and converts it to US GPM
    BB = L.Value * 3.2808    'takes the value in f and converts it to feet
    CC = W.Value * 3.2808    'takes the value in f and converts it to feet
    DD = AA - (AA * (Math.Pow(BB, 2) / (Math.Pow(CC, 2))))    'the math bit
    CF.Text = String.Format("{0:n2}", DD)    'puts result in this textbox
End Sub
```

The end figure I am after is 323.84 but it insists on rounding the result up to 324
I put `string.format("{0:n2}",DD)` to show 2 decimal places but they show as .00, not .84.

Can anyone help me sort this through please?

Comment: If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) it will point out problems like trying to assign a floating-point value to an integer variable. However, it won't point out that the label for the units of Corner Flow should be "US GPM", not "l/s".

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `AA`, `BB`, `CC`, and `DD` as integers.  Integers can only store whole numbers.  Depending on what this data represents, you either want to use a `Decimal` or a `Double`.

Comment: That's the one, I used Double and it worked for me, thank you very much .